# Standard deviation from iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, statistics

I want this to be similar to the STL algorithms but I don't find it elegant nor concise at all:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using E = double;
template <typename IT>
E std_dev(IT begin, IT end){
    auto N = std::distance(begin, end);
    E average = std::accumulate(begin, end, E()) / N;
    auto sum_term = [average](E init, E value)-> E{ 
        return init + (value - average)*(value - average);
    };
    E variance = std::accumulate(begin,  end, E(), sum_term);
    return std::sqrt(variance * 1.0 / (N - 1));
}


int main(){
    std::vector<double> stuff {3.5, 3.4, 3.6, 3.9, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5};
    std::cout << std_dev(stuff.begin(), stuff.end()) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Please do not change the code in your questions after an answer has been posted, so as not to invalidate it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, make it correct.

`N` is integral, you could make it `E` so you don't accidentally do integer arithmetic.

`N-1` is wrong.

Rename `average` to `mean`.

Don't hardcode `E`.

You get:

```
template <typename It, typename E = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>
E std_dev(It begin, It end){
    E N = std::distance(begin, end);
    E const mean = std::accumulate(begin, end, E()) / N;
    auto sum_term = [mean](E init, E value)-> E { return init + (value - mean)*(value - mean); };
    E variance = std::accumulate(begin, end, E(), sum_term);
    return std::sqrt(variance / N);
}
```

Slightly stylized, with comparison to Boost Accumulator:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7539ff4b026a60bc)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics.hpp>

template <typename It, typename E = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type, typename R = typename std::common_type<double, E>::type>
R std_dev_boost(It begin, It end){
    namespace ba = boost::accumulators;

    ba::accumulator_set<R, ba::stats<ba::tag::variance> > accu;
    std::for_each(begin, end, std::ref(accu));
    return std::sqrt(ba::variance(accu));
}

template <typename It, 
    typename E = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type, 
    typename R = typename std::common_type<double, E>::type>
R std_dev(It b, It e)
{
    R N          = std::distance(b, e);
    R const mean = std::accumulate(b, e, R{}) / N;
    R variance   = std::accumulate(b, e, R{}, [mean](R a, E v)-> R { return a + (v-mean)*(v-mean); });
    return std::sqrt(variance / N);
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> stuff {35, 34, 36, 39, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35};
    std::cout << std_dev_boost(stuff.begin(), stuff.end()) << "\n";
    std::cout << std_dev      (stuff.begin(), stuff.end()) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
1.34256
1.34256
```

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Mmm. I was mistaken there. The `N-1` seems to be the only mistake that made the outcome wrong :)

Comment: Ah. Well, see my update for how to derive a proper result type that works even if the input is an integer container.

Comment: The `N-1` isn't wrong. It's just computing a *different* standard deviation. To be specific, if you're computing the standard deviation of "the universe", you use `N`. If you're computing the standard deviation of a sample, you use `N-1`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yeah, that was clear to me since Giraffe told me :) I was content contributing the style feedback

Answer (score -3):

A simple conciseness improvement would be to inline non-informative variables:

```
template <typename IT>
E std_dev(IT begin, IT end) {
    auto N = std::distance(begin, end);
    E variance = std::accumulate(begin,  end, E{},
        [average=std::accumulate(begin, end, E{}) / N](E init, E value) -> E
    {
        return init + (value - average)*(value - average);
    });
    return std::sqrt(variance * 1.0 / (N - 1));
}
```

`average` was moved into the lambda capture (C++14(?)) and the lambda itself was passed directly to `std::accumulate`.

Comment: You left in all the bugs.

Comment: @sehe No, I didn't remove them. I'm here for conciseness (as stated in the answer), not for correctness.

Comment: The main point of programming is to make it easier to read not more concise.

Comment: If you want it concise, use `valarray`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1723071/179910